# It doesn't appear any item in a Listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm using an SQLite database in my project and I have a ListView on my main activity (`BancoDictionary`). This ListView should display all words from `KEY_WORD` (column) without typing anything (like a Dictionary). I created an array list in my database activity (`DictionaryDatabase`) to get all words. My application runs ok, but doesn't show any item in a ListView. Why?

The code is below:

DictionaryDatabase.java

```
public class DictionaryDatabase {
    private static final String TAG = "DictionaryDatabase";

    public static final String KEY_WORD = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1;
    public static final String KEY_DEFINITION = SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dictionary";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTSdictionary";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final DictionaryOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;
    private static final HashMap<String,String> mColumnMap = buildColumnMap();

    public DictionaryDatabase(Context context) {
        mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DictionaryOpenHelper(context);
    }

    private static HashMap<String,String> buildColumnMap() {
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put(KEY_WORD, KEY_WORD);
        map.put(KEY_DEFINITION, KEY_DEFINITION);
        map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
        map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
            SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
        return map;
    }

    public Cursor getWord(String rowId, String[] columns) {
        String selection = "rowid = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {rowId};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
    }

    public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
        String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
    }

    private Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
        builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
            columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    private static class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {    
        private final Context mHelperContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

        private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " USING fts3 (" + KEY_WORD + ", " + KEY_DEFINITION + ");";

        DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            mHelperContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
            loadDictionary();
        }

        private void loadDictionary() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        loadWords();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        private void loadWords() throws IOException {
            Log.d(TAG, "Loading words...");
            final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
            InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.definitions);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, "//");
                    if (strings.length < 2)
                        continue;
                    long id = addWord(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim());
                    if (id < 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "DONE loading words.");
        }

        public long addWord(String word, String definition) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_WORD, word);
            initialValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, definition);

            return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

I think the problem starts here.

```
public ArrayList<WordDefinition> getAllWords() {
    ArrayList<WordDefinition> arrayList=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();
    SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectAllQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE;
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectAllQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {            
            WordDefinition wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)));
            arrayList.add(wordDefinition);              
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());          
    }   
    return arrayList;
}

public WordDefinition getWordDefinition(String word) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    WordDefinition wordDefinition=null;

    String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE+ " WHERE "+KEY_WORD+" = '"+word+ "'";
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)));

    }   
    return wordDefinition;
}

public WordDefinition getWordDefinition(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    WordDefinition wordDefinition=null;

    String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE+ " WHERE "+BaseColumns._ID+" = '"+id+ "'";
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_WORD)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DEFINITION)));  
    }   

    return wordDefinition;
}

public void initializeDatabaseFortheFirstTime(ArrayList<WordDefinition> wordDefinitions) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=mDatabaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("BEGIN");

    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

    for (WordDefinition wordDefinition : wordDefinitions) {
        contentValues.put(KEY_WORD, wordDefinition.KEY_WORD);
        contentValues.put(KEY_DEFINITION, wordDefinition.KEY_DEFINITION);           
        database.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }
    database.execSQL("COMMIT");

    }
}
```

WordDefinition.java

```
public class WordDefinition {
    String KEY_WORD,KEY_DEFINITION;

    public WordDefinition(String KEY_WORD,ArrayList<String> alldefinition) {
        this.KEY_WORD=KEY_WORD;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        for (String string : alldefinition) {
            stringBuilder.append(string);
        }       
        this.KEY_WORD=stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public WordDefinition(String KEY_WORD,String alldefinition) {
        this.KEY_WORD=KEY_WORD;     
        this.KEY_DEFINITION=alldefinition;
    }
}
```

BancoDictionary.java

```
public class BancoDictionary extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private ListView mListView;

    ListView dictionaryListView;

    String logTagString="DICTIONARY";
    ArrayList<WordDefinition> allWordDefinitions=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();


    DictionaryDatabase DictionaryDatabase;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.d("DICTIONARY", "second activity started");

        dictionaryListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.dictionaryListView);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        DictionaryDatabase=new DictionaryDatabase(this);
        allWordDefinitions=DictionaryDatabase.getAllWords();

        dictionaryListView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
                if (view==null) {
                    view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                }
                TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItemTextView);
                textView.setText(allWordDefinitions.get(position).KEY_WORD);

                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return allWordDefinitions.size();
            }
        });

        dictionaryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(BancoDictionary.this, WordActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("KEY_WORD", allWordDefinitions.get(position).KEY_WORD);
                intent.putExtra("KEY_DEFINITION", allWordDefinitions.get(position).KEY_DEFINITION);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
            this.finish();
            wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
            startActivity(wordIntent);
        } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            showResults(query);
        }
    }

    private void showResults(String query) {
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, new String[] {query}, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
        } else {
            int count = cursor.getCount();
            String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results, count, new Object[] {count, query});
            mTextView.setText(countString);

            String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD, DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word, R.id.definition };

            SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                      R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
            mListView.setAdapter(words);

            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                    Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(id));
                    wordIntent.setData(data);
                    startActivity(wordIntent);

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
         searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        }

        return true;
    } 

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                onSearchRequested();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you done **any** debugging to see about where the problem might be? Check that you are getting the data from the db successfully, is getView() called, ... You've posted four classes for us to dig through with nothing else to go on.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but on the inflate call, you're setting the parent to null, which is not the proper use.  Use the 3 parameter inflate, and set the attachToRoot parameter to false:
`getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, arg2, false);`  Also read this: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: @Sector95 It worked!!! But now, when I click on some item, the application stops and closes.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.  In regards to your second bit, you'll have to look at the stack trace to find out what's causing the application to crash.

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.  It both awards the contributor points, and makes it easy for other users to find the solution without sifting through comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the inflate call, you're setting the parent to null, which is not the proper use. Use the 3 parameter inflate, and set the attachToRoot parameter to false: `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, arg2, false);`

This site has a great explanation as to why this is necessary: http://www.possiblemobile.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended